# how to create a custom master page without top ribbon bar?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, master-page

I am using SP 2013 and have a publish site collection. I want to create a custom master page but no top ribbon bar.

I followed below documentation but it still has top bar.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-convert-an-html-file-into-a-master-page-in-sharepoint

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS to hide the Ribbon Bar:

```
#s4-ribbonrow{
  visibilityhidden;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Hide ribbon bar in SharePoint 2013 master page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/300d07c8-b285-4165-8fbb-3dcf33eb254a/hide-ribbon-bar-in-sharepoint-2013-master-page?forum=sharepointcustomization)